# Merging two statements into one statement

Tags: python

Is it possible to merging the following two statements into one statement?

```
f.write(",".join(str(cell) for cell in row))
f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm more interested in _why_ you want this. Does your workplace have a shortage of newline characters? :-)

Comment: Have you considered using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead?

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate the result of `join` with the `'\n'`

```
f.write(",".join(str(cell) for cell in row) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string formating:

```
f.write("{}\n".format(",".join(str(cell) for cell in row)))
```

*Note* that this is significantly slower than most other methods, including the two separate writes as per the OP, and the older (deprecated) style of string formatting (e.g. `f.write("%s\n", ...)`.

See [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? [The `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) will do this for you:

```
import csv

rows = [['foo', 1, 2], ['bar', 3, 4]]

with open("filename.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do with my wrapper library `pyexcel`:

```
import pyexcel

rows = [['foo', 1, 2], ['bar', 3, 4]]
w = pyexcel.Writer("file.csv")
w.write_rows(rows)
w.close()
```

And the documentation is [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/)